# mdadm: failed to write superblock

Tags: linux, raid

I'm quite new to RAID, and I'm having a problem. My server warned me that some drive is faulty, so I investigated:

```
root@server:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md1 : active raid1 sda1[2](F) sdb1[1]
      10485696 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sda2[2](F) sdb2[1]
      965746624 blocks [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

It looks like that sda1 and sda2 are faulty.
So I tried to remove sda1

```
root@server:~# mdadm /dev/md1 -r /dev/sda1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sda1 from /dev/md1
```

I'm trying to understand what should I do now: if I try to add the device again I get this message:

```
root@server:~# mdadm /dev/md1 -a /dev/sda1
mdadm: failed to write superblock to /dev/sda1
```

I suppose I'm missing some rebuilding/restore step.
How can I restore the RAID system again?

**UPDATE:**

dmesg output shows a lot of these, so there's some evidence of hardware failure:

```
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 10 07 00 00 01 00
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4103
```

Comment: You seem to have shot right past the important possibility: that `sda1` was failed out of the array because it's actually faulty, or in some other way unsuitable.  Could you address that before moving on to "*how do I persuade the RAID subsystem to accept this perfectly good drive*"?

Comment: Can you try to clear the superblock first with "mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1"? Does it help? Can you check kernel events in the log file  /var/log/messages and dmesg command? Are there any disk errors? You can check SMART attributes of that disk with "smartctl -a /dev/sda".

Comment: Thanks, I added some dmesg output. `smartctl` fails (A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting.)

Comment: At first sight, it looks like faulty disk. What distro and kernel do you run? What disk controller is used to connect the disks? What disk model do you use? I think badblocks tool won't help as well.

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 12.10 [...] 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP. It's a dedicated server on OVH. I guess I have to contact their technical support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdadm has marked the drive as faulty and your log is showing errors on the drive.

This means the drive is broken and has to be replaced. There's no point in readding it to the RAID.